# VSCodeのデバッグ(python)で1つのargsに複数の値を入力する方法

Tags: python, vscode

VSCodeのデバッグ(python)で1つのargsに複数の値を入力する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか

例えば、下記のshellscriptのように、lr-stepsに16と22の2つの値を入力したいと考えております。
(このshellscriptは問題なく実行出来ます)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 \
python \
train.py \
--lr-steps 16 22 \
```

上記のshellscriptの内容でデバッグするために、launch.jsonを下記のように書いてみましたがうまくいきませんでした。

```js
{
    // IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
    // 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
    // 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "python": "/home/hoge/anaconda3/envs/huga/bin/python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "train.py",
            "cwd": "/home/hoge/projects/huga",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "env": { 
                "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":"3"},
            "args": [
                "--lr-steps=[16,22]",
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

他にも下記のように--lr-stepsの部分を書き換えてみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
`"--lr-steps=[16,22]"`
`"--lr-steps=16,22"`
`"--lr-steps=16 22"`

実行するpythonのスクリプトは下記の通りです。

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument('--lr-steps', default=[16, 22], nargs='+', type=int, help='decrease lr every step-size epochs')
```

--lr-stepsに整数のリストを代入するには、どのようにlaunch.jsonで指定すればよいかご教授頂けないでしょうか。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `=`,`[`,`,`,`]`の各種記号は使わずに全部空白だけで区切ってみてはどうでしょう？ [python argh/argparse: How can I pass a list as a command-line argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398065/python-argh-argparse-how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument)

Comment: @kunif 様 早速コメントいただきありがとうございます。イコールを外して、 `"--lr-steps 16 22"` としてみましたが、下記のようなエラーが表示されてしまいうまくいきませんでした。`train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --lr-steps 16 2`

Comment: @oriri さんの回答と同等の効果を期待したのですが、VSCodeでは指定方法の差で何か違う処理がされているのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code の `launch.json` で引数 (`args`) を指定する場合
もともと "args"は list構造になっているので, 複数指定することができます

```js
            "args": [
                "--lr-steps", "16", "22"
            ]
```

(`ArgumentParser` として引数を文字列で与え 結果を数値で取得する, はずなので
あとの数字も文字列として指定します)

Comment: oriri様 ご回答いただきありがとうございます。無事に実行することが出来ました。